# Wildfly EAR deployed application location path

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, ear

My question may sound obvious but i'm quite new working with Wildfly 9 !

I deployed my EAR in server via admin console. My Wildfly is in standalone mode. I couldn't where the ear was deployed ! Is there any specific folder for deployed applications in wildfly ?

Thanks!

[EDIT]

I want to know about deployed location because of class loading in wildfly. I attempted to load a resource which is a .exe from classpasth but it render a wierd path:

```
Event.class.getResource("/Decorder/Decoder.exe")
```

I get the following out put in wildfly logs :

```
C:\apps\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\bin\content\SYSE.ear\SYSE-components-3.0.jar\Decoder\Decoder.exe
```

I don't know from were the resource path above is coming from !

Answer (score 1):

You have deployed your ear throught the webconsole or cli, it is a managed content and as such is managed through the ContentRepoistory in WildFly. It should be under standalone/data/content + hash part.
This looks quite weird to me : C:\apps\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\bin\content\SYSE.ear

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED to new question]
This all comes down to how you packaged and configured your deployment.

`/Decorder/Decoder.exe` might be a valid path if you provided the file in `/resources/Decorder/Decoder.exe`. This is due to the fact that the classloader will provide all of your resources relative to your root, which in most cases is the jar component.

Note: maybe it is already resolved by removing the typo in your path: `/Decorder/Decoder.exe` -> `/Decoder/Decoder.exe`

Comment: I updated my question above to highlight the details of my current issue, thanks for your reply

Comment: Ok, thanks for the update. I will check back for a better answer ;-)